# Let $f(x) = \sum_{r_n < x} 2^{-n}$, where $(r_n)$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Why is $f$ discontinuous everywhere in $[0, 1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

I think I have that $f$ is discontinuous at every $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, since if $q = r_k \in (r_n)$, then we consider $(x_n) \rightarrow q$ from below and $(y_n) \rightarrow q$ from above where $x_n, y_n \in \mathbb{Q} \; \forall n$. Let $x = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n)$ and $y = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(y_n)$. Then we have $d(y,x) = 2^{-k}$, so $y \not= x$ and so $f$ is discontinuous at every $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. But why is $f$ discontinuous at every irrational as well?

Comment: Since $f$ is monotonic, it allows at most countably many discontinuities.

Comment: @QiyuWen hmm then there is an error in Carothers Real Analysis as there is a problem where he asks one to prove this. I am familiar with that result though, so you are right. Not sure why I didnt think of that, I guess I just assumed it was true as it was a problem in the book.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723504/fx-sum-n-infty-frac12n-chi-r-n-infty-is-right-continuous?rq=1).

Answer (score 4):

No, $f$ is continuous at every irrational. Actually,
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}\chi_{\{x:r_n<x\}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x).$$
For every irrational $x_0$, $f_n(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ for all $n$. Since the series $\sum f_n(x)$ is convergent uniformly(for $|f_n(x)|\leq\frac1{2^n}$), $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: Could the downvoter leave a comment please?

Comment: +1. Neat proof.