# Where $f(x) = \sum_{r_n \leq x} \frac{1}{2^n}$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

First I have to write the set of all rational numbers as a sequence.  Let the sequence be $\{r_n\}$.

$f(x) = \sum_{r_n \leq x} \frac{1}{2^n}$

I have to find where the function is continuous.

**My Attempt:** We know for every $\epsilon > 0$   we will get a natural number $k$  such that  $\sum_{n = k}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n} < \epsilon$.   We can use it and show $f(x)$  is continuous at irrational numbers.

Can anyone please tell me if I am wrong ?

Comment: It is continuous at all irrational points and not continuous at any rational point.

Comment: For some information about this function see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723504/fx-sum-n-infty-frac12n-chi-r-n-infty-is-right-continuous?rq=1

Comment: Yes you are right. If $c = r_k$ is a rational number then for all $x < c$  , $|f(c) - f(x)|$  will be greater than $\frac{1}{2^k}$@KaviRamaMurthy